# Creating sentence after looping through each letter of word in string

Tags: python, python-3.x

For the following code, I want the output so that there is a space to match each word in the input string after each consonant in a word has been converted. My current strategy is using lists but it prevents me from putting a space between each word.

Example- if input is: "a cat", result should be "a CashaTut", instead of "aCashaTut".

```
string = input("Enter input string: ")
list = string.split(' ')
output_1 = []


def converted_(word):
    for letter in word:
        if letter in 'Bb':
            return word.replace(letter, "Bub")
        elif letter in 'Cc': 
            return word.replace(letter, 'Cash') 
        elif letter in 'Dd':
            return word.replace(letter, 'Dud') 
        elif letter in 'Ff':
            return word.replace(letter, 'Fud') 
        elif letter in 'Gg':
            return word.replace(letter, 'Gug') 
        elif letter in 'Hh':
            return word.replace(letter, 'Hash') 
        elif letter in 'Jj':
            return word.replace(letter, 'Jay') 
        elif letter in 'Kk':
            return word.replace(letter, 'Kuck') 
        elif letter in 'Ll':
            return word.replace(letter, 'Lul') 
        elif letter in 'Mm':
            return word.replace(letter, 'Mum') 
        elif letter in 'Nn':
            return word.replace(letter, 'Nun') 
        elif letter in 'Pp':
            return word.replace(letter, 'Pub') 
        elif letter in 'Qq':
            return word.replace(letter, 'Quack') 
        elif letter in 'Rr':
            return word.replace(letter, 'Rug')
        elif letter in 'Ss':
            return word.replace(letter, 'Sus') 
        elif letter in 'Tt':
            return word.replace(letter, 'Tut') 
        elif letter in 'Vv':
            return word.replace(letter, 'Vuv') 
        elif letter in 'Ww':
            return word.replace(letter, 'Wack') 
        elif letter in 'Xx':
            return word.replace(letter, 'Ex') 
        elif letter in 'Yy':
            return word.replace(letter, 'Yub') 
        elif letter in 'Zz':
            return word.replace(letter, 'Zub') 
        else:
            return word
        

             

for i in range(len(list)):
    word = list[i]
    for j in range(len(word)):
        letter = word[j]
        var_part = funny_2(letter)
        output_1.append(var_part)
        a = ''.join(output_1)

print(a)
```

Comment: `funny_2(letter)` ? you are not using `converted_`

Comment: Don't you miss a space in `a = ''.join(output_1)`: `a = ' '.join(output_1)`

Comment: returning from your funciton will leave it - so you get 1 letter replaced at most.

Answer (score 2):

why to split by space at all? just loop over the entire line and spaces will remain.

try this:

```
def converted_(line):
    new_string = ''
    for letter in line:
        if letter in 'Bb':
            new_string+="Bub"
        elif letter in 'Cc': 
            new_string+='Cash' 
        elif letter in 'Dd':
            new_string+='Dud'
        elif letter in 'Ff':
            new_string+='Fud' 
        elif letter in 'Gg':
            new_string+='Gug'
        elif letter in 'Hh':
            new_string+='Hash'
        elif letter in 'Jj':
            new_string+='Jay'
        elif letter in 'Kk':
            new_string+='Kuck'
        elif letter in 'Ll':
            new_string+='Lul' 
        elif letter in 'Mm':
            new_string+='Mum' 
        elif letter in 'Nn':
            new_string+='Nun' 
        elif letter in 'Pp':
            new_string+='Pub' 
        elif letter in 'Qq':
            new_string+='Quack' 
        elif letter in 'Rr':
            new_string+='Rug'
        elif letter in 'Ss':
            new_string+='Sus' 
        elif letter in 'Tt':
            new_string+='Tut' 
        elif letter in 'Vv':
            new_string+= 'Vuv'
        elif letter in 'Ww':
            new_string+='Wack'
        elif letter in 'Xx':
            new_string+='Ex' 
        elif letter in 'Yy':
            new_string+='Yub' 
        elif letter in 'Zz':
            new_string+='Zub'
        else:
            new_string+=letter
    return new_string
        
m_in = input("Enter input string: ")
m_out = converted_(m_in)
print(m_out)
```

output:

```
Enter input string: a cat

a CashaTut
```

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out in other answers, there is no requirement to `split` the input `str` within your program.

I would have a think about the `if`/`elif`/`else` logic within your code. In cases where no substitution is required, each of these conditions will be checked at runtime until the `else` statement is hit. Similarly, for iterations on the character `z`/`Z`, each of the previous conditions will be checked before a `True` value is returned by `elif letter in 'Zz':`. This probably won't cause long waits for execution given a sufficiently short input `str`, however from an efficiency and readability perspective it probably isn't the best practice.

The below solution makes use of a `dict` (`mapping`) which has keys for each consonant which are mapped to values representing the value which will be used to replace them if found in the input `str`.

```py
mapping = {
    'b': 'Bub',
    'c': 'Cash',
    'd': 'Dud',
    'f': 'Fud',
    'g': 'Gug',
    'h': 'Hash',
    'j': 'Jay',
    'k': 'Kuck',
    'l': 'Lul',
    'm': 'Mum',
    'n': 'Nun',
    'p': 'Pub',
    'q': 'Quack',
    'r': 'Rug',
    's': 'Sus',
    't': 'Tut',
    'v': 'Vuv',
    'w': 'Wack',
    'x': 'Ex',
    'y': 'Yub',
    'z': 'Zub' 
}

def converted_(word):
    return ''.join([mapping.get(c.lower()) or c for c in word])

string = input("Enter input string: ")
output = converted_(string)
print(output)
```

Now the `converted_` function uses a `list` comprehension to return a `str` in constructed by iterating across each character of the `str` passed at runtime (`word`) and adding either:

1. The value mapped to the current character in `mapping` - if the current character converted to lowercase exists as a key within `mapping`.
2. The current character - if a lowercase conversion of it does not exist as a key within `mapping`.

In this implementation, only 1 comparison is necessary for each character to be converted properly - i.e. "Is a lowercase version present as a key in `mapping`?" - as opposed to your original code in which `1...21` comparisons are made to convert each character depending on its value.